# Can't create virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create new virtual device. After selecting device definition, then selecting the system image, I'm unable to proceed because there is no emulator installed. Below is a screenshot of my configuration screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/miNGw.jpg

Even after I clicked Install Emulator nothing happens. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep your SDK Tools up to date.
If they are up to date try to reinstall them using the SDK manager, this might fix the issue.